# android spinner item onclick text change

Tags: android

i am newcomer in android domain. , please help me .

i have two string array ,from one array with the help of adapter i get the spinner drop down view.the thing is that when i click the drop down list i have to populate the value of the same position from the second array. i paste my code. please help me.

**Code :**

```
class programList extends AsyncTask<String, Long, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = "http://mydomain.com/app/getdata.php?type=program_list&id="
                + surveyId;
        String output = null;

        JSONParserList Jparser = new JSONParserList();

        output = Jparser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("JSONRESPONSE", output);
        try {

            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(output);

            JSONArray OUTPUT = jObject.getJSONArray("OUTPUT");
            String[] allStates = new String[OUTPUT.length()+1];
            String[] allDistrics = new String[OUTPUT.length()];
            allStates[0] = "Select Program";


            for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject eachProgram = OUTPUT.getJSONObject(i);

                String adb = eachProgram.getString("adp");

                String district = eachProgram.getString("district");

                String location = eachProgram.getString("location");

                String p_id = eachProgram.getString("p_id");

                ProgramList programlist = new ProgramList();

                programlist.setAdp(adb);
                programlist.setDistrict(district);
                programlist.setLocation(location);
                programlist.setP_id(p_id);
                // programlist.setAdpList(adb);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "id: " + programlist.getP_id(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                programList.add(programlist);
                allStates[i+1] = adb;
                allDistrics[i] = district;
            }
            // programDropDown();
            Spinner sprogram = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterstate = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    startSurvey.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    allStates);
            sprogram.setAdapter(adapterstate);

            sprogram.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     String program = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    // long id1 = adapter.getId();
                     **String d = allDistrics[position-1];**


                        // Showing selected spinner item
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Program position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }


                });

            // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

my error is given on that star position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All districts isn't available at that scope, also you need to include the actual log cat errors when you post a question like this please

**Edit**

Actually variable being available *may* be your problem, but position I believe is zero-index just like the array and so may also be a problem: position-1 can = -1 and be out of bounds

To fix the scope of your districts variable you can use the final keyword `final String[] districts ...`

Comment: already i used final keyword but still its not solving the issue.and for position-1: when i took the array  allStates then i gave a static value on 0th position so my rest of the value's position is start from 1th position .but my allDistrics array , my id is inserted from 0th position. so i use position-1 to get the value of destrict

Comment: You still haven't posted your log cat error, no-one will be likely to solve it without that

Comment: thanks Nick.i solve that problem .this problem is occur due to the position-1 value.thanks for your suggestion